# Display WebView in landscape WITHOUT screen rotation

Tags: android, android-webview

I have some content for a WebView that would look better in landscape format.  I've found solutions which would enable me to force landscape orientation when displaying the WebView, which achieves the goal, but in a way that I don't like.

In particular, I don't think it's a great user experience to have the actual screen rotation changed suddenly, without warning and without having requested this, so that everything sort of spins in front of your eyes, with the status bar etc moving from top to side.

I'd prefer that the actual screen rotation is left alone, so that it remains in portrait orientation if that is what it is presently set.  All that needs to happen is that the page within the WebView is displayed sideways, in landscape orientation.

Is that possible?

Comment: That is somehow possible. I am just wondering that it would look so weird from User's perspective. If I would be a user, I would be fine that my notification bar is shifting, but I would be creeped if I see my notification bar on a different orientation with my webpage.

Comment: That's a fair comment, and I'm not yet convinced that this alternative of just rotating the webpage within the webview is any better from a UI perspective.  I will try Antonio's clever suggestion below and see which is more pleasant (or less unpleasant) for the user.  Another option is to display the webpage in portrait, with a quick Toast message to hint that it may look better (fit better into the screen) if the user turns the screen sideways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try create a custom WebView like:

```
public class VWebView extends WebView {
    final boolean topDown = true;

    public VWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (topDown) {
            canvas.translate(getHeight(), 0);
            canvas.rotate(90);
        } else {
            canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
            canvas.rotate(-90);
        }
        canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<com.my.package.VWebView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</com.my.package.VWebView>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I think that the method VerticalWebView(...) should be VWebView(...).  When I try this, it nearly works.  The web page is rotated, but the page (chart) appears to be cut off where it would have been cut off if displayed in portrait format.  It's a potentially neat solution though!

Comment: yes this is my solution for vertical, you can configure it for your need.

Comment: A followup... I couldn't quite get this to work for my needs (I think it's because the html content I am displaying is interactive, so maybe it doesn't work so well after being rotated by this method).  However, I see it as being a valid solution so I've marked it as such.  It was also very useful to me to see how WebView could be extended in this way to create a custom WebView, and I have now used such a custom WebView for another purpose (in order to render the WebView *after* grabbing the x,y dimensions of the WebView). So thanks.

Comment: @drmrbrewer It was a pleasure to help you :D!!