# How to force portrait orientation my app on an android box?

Tags: android

So I have this app that's set to display on portrait mode. When I run it on android, it goes "portrait" but only in the center of the screen. It doesn't do what you'll except. For example on tablets where it goes portrait mode and fills the entire screen.

I tried every well-known root access app but they can't give me root access to be able to edit build.prop. KingRoot even said that my device is too strong.

So, what I planned now is do it via code. My app is quite simple so it won't give me a lot of problems on the design side of things. It just contains a webview and nothing else.

I want it to work even on non-Android TV boxes because we use various kinds on android boxes and it'll be a problem for me if it will only work on real Android TV boxes.

After some experimenting, I made this code.

```
if(forcePotrait){
    webview.setRotation(-90f);

    int measuredWidth = 0;
    int measuredHeight = 0;
    Point size = new Point();
    WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)    {
        w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
        measuredWidth = size.x;
        measuredHeight = size.y;
    }else{
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        measuredWidth = d.getWidth();
        measuredHeight = d.getHeight();
    }

    int[] scrData = getScreenDimension();

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lytParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(scrData[1], scrData[0]);

    lytMain.removeAllViews();
    lytMain.addView(webview, 0, lytParams);

}
```

`getScreenDimension` is a method that get the screen size of the device.

It rotates the `WebView` but it occupies just a portion of the screen and displays just a portion of the page as well. I'm using `ConstraintLayout` as my base layout. I also turned on the `Show Layout Bounds` on `Developer Options` and it seems like the `WebView` is not drawn properly because the red line is a few dps of the center which isn't anywhere near the `WebView`s display.

[image]
I found this and used it on my project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26711189/10464730. This is the code in the link.

```
public class VWebView extends WebView {
    final boolean topDown = true;

    public VWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (topDown) {
            canvas.translate(getHeight(), 0);
            canvas.rotate(90);
        } else {
            canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
            canvas.rotate(-90);
        }
        canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Now, I don't need to rotate the `WebView` manually. But the `WebView` still doesn't fill the entire screen.

[image]

With the code below which uses values that are close to what I get on screen size methods, I get the screenshot result.

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lytParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(1300, 1280);
webview.setLayoutParams(lytParams);
```

[image]

Comment: Is the Android box running Android TV? See: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts

Comment: As much as possible I want it to work even on non-Android TV boxes.

Comment: If you force an app orientation to portrait mode only, you will get the first case. Why don't you add support for the landscape view design? For TV, it is naturally a landscape oriented device, so it is natural to design a TV app in landscape view. But, if you need both viewing modes, then support both and you can programmatically configure the app orientation to landscape mode when it detects a TV device.

Comment: The app is a kiosk app so I need it on portrait mode. On the support for landscape mode, the layout I have only contains a webview. Do I really need to have a layout_land version of the layout?

Comment: Do you have solution?