# How to rotate webview android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to rotate my webview in landshape without rotating mobile.

How can I rotate webview in android ?

[I followed this answer to rotate webview in android.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26711189/14118103)

**VWebView.java**

```
public class VWebView extends WebView {
    final boolean topDown = true;

    public VWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (topDown) {
            canvas.translate(getHeight(), 0);
            canvas.rotate(90);
        } else {
            canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
            canvas.rotate(-90);
        }
        canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<com.my.package.VWebView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</com.my.package.VWebView>
```

If I run this program an error occured at this line

```
     canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
```

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.webview, PID: 12119
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed
    at android.graphics.Canvas.checkValidClipOp(Canvas.java:853)
    at android.graphics.Canvas.clipRect(Canvas.java:992)
    at com.example.webview.VWebView.draw(VWebView.java:24)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22776)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23631)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:5336)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:5093)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1994)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22762)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23631)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:5336)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:5093)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22762)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23631)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:5336)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:5093)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22762)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23631)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:5336)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:5093)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22762)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23631)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:5336)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:5093)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22762)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23631)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:5336)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:5093)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23904)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:1284)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22776)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:579)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:585)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:662)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:5042)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:4749)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3866)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2618)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9971)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1010)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:809)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:744)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:995)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

What I did wrong in this ?

I want to rotate my webview in landshape without rotating mobile.

How can I rotate webview in android ?

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate with Animation.
Here is a code:

```
AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
animSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animSet.setFillAfter(true);
animSet.setFillEnabled(true);

final RotateAnimation animRotate = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, -90.0f,
    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, 
    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

animRotate.setDuration(1500);
animRotate.setFillAfter(true);
animSet.addAnimation(animRotate);

myWebView.startAnimation(animSet);
```

Comment: this code not worked properly . image ::  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/45443554/173180672-97bcd2bd-3870-4406-9b4c-2928b4e4c43c.jpg

Comment: Did you try to control the angel or duration time?

Comment: I want to rotate webview . my full project : https://github.com/PradeepSimba/webviewrotate